# Missing Add Index Arrow in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

When adding an index on my old machine I would use the below option to bring up the dialog box:

[image]

But on my new machine it is missing the little black right arrows:

[image]

And bringing up the T SQL you can see on the right when you click "new index..."

I'm connected directly to Azure SQL and my table is as below:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Why not just do it "properly" and write the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have those options available when you are connected to Azure SQL Database. They are only available when you are connected to SQL Server instances.

It is a limitation of Azure SQL Database the user experience with SSMS is not yet the same, when you choose to create a "New index" using SSMS (as you have shown on the images you have included on your question) then SSMS will create a T-SQL index template on the query window, and the same will happen to create some of the Azure SQL Database objects, including logins, roles, schemas and statistics.

However, when you create logins, roles, schemas and statistics with SSMS on a database attached to a SQL Server instance then SSMS gives you a GUI dialog to create them.